# Getting TextField values into database as int type- JavaFx

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am getting the values from the interface and handle them in the controller. 
The string values are saved to the database successfully, but the integer values are being failed to be saved.

```
@FXML
private TextField productId;
@FXML
private TextArea resultArea;
@FXML
private TextArea description;
@FXML
private TextField newUnitPrice;
@FXML
private TextField title;
@FXML
private TextField newQuantity;
@FXML
private TextField unitPrice;
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> type;
@FXML
private TextField quantity;

ObservableList<String> productType = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Food","Construction","Electric","Grocery");

int unitPriceInt;
int quantityInt;
int newUnitPriceInt;
int productIdInt;
int newQuantityInt;


public void initComponents() {
    this.unitPriceInt = Integer.parseInt(unitPrice.getText());
    this.quantityInt = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());
    this.newUnitPriceInt = Integer.parseInt(newUnitPrice.getText());
    this.newUnitPriceInt = Integer.parseInt(newQuantity.getText());
    this.productIdInt = Integer.parseInt(productId.getText());

}

//Insert a product to the DB
@FXML
private void insertProduct(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        ProductDAO.insertProduct(title.getText(), type.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(), description.getText(), unitPriceInt, quantityInt);
        resultArea.setText("Product inserted! \n");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        resultArea.setText("Problem occurred while inserting product item" + e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Even though the strings are casted into Integer type the values are not binding to the variables. They are saved as 0.

Comment: Failed means that you get an exception or wrong values are persisted?

Comment: Nothing gets persisted. No exception occurs

Comment: this code does not see the initialization of the `unitPriceInt` and `quantityInt` fields. You only see that you are accentuated in `initComponents()`. But when / when calling this feature is not clear. So, normally `unitPriceInt` and `quantityInt` have default values (o) or wrong (current to the last `initComponents()` call).